# finding the maximum number in the binary tree but only amongst the leaf nodes

Tags: c, binary-tree

if i have a binary tree such

```
            3
          /   \
         7     8
        / \   / \
       2   3 4   6
```

I made a program to find the maximum value on the binary tree

```
int max_val(node *head){
    
    int leftmax, rightmax;

    int max = head->val;

    if (head->left != NULL) {
        leftmax = max_val(head->left);
        max = (max > leftmax) ? max : leftmax;
    }

    if (head->right != NULL) {
        rightmax = max_val(head->right);
        max = (max > rightmax) ? max : rightmax;
    }

    return max;
```

along with all the structs and stuff.

However this program will return 8 as 8 is the biggest value in the tree. Is there any way to limit the comparisons to only leaf nodes (so between 2, 3, 4, 6) and make it return 6 instead?

Comment: Of course there is a way. A value of a subtree should be the maximum value of its subtrees, unless it is a leaf. So you need to traverse *both* left and right subtrees first, then compare their values, not to compare with the value of the current node as you are doing here

Comment: That is a strange thing to ask. Is it always going to be complete? Maybe a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation) would be better for whatever it is your doing?

Comment: how are those keys sorted? what is the relation between the keys of the parent node and its children? what is the relation between keys in the left and right child?

Answer (score 2):

The head node either has no subtrees, 1 subtree, or 2 subtrees.

if it has no subtrees, the associated value is the max.
if it has 1 subtree, the max is the max of that subtree.
if it has 2 subtrees, the max is the largest value among the max's in the subtrees.

Answer (score -2):

You should check all the leaves and the find the max there.

You can modify your code like this:

```
int max_val(node *head){
    if (head->left == null && head->right == null)
        return head->val;

    left = -∞;
    if (head->left!= null)
        left = max_val(*head->left);

    right = -∞;
    if (head->right != null)
        right = max_val(*head->right);

    return left > right ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: I've never used the ∞ symbol in C source code before!  Does your C compiler let you do that?

Comment: The question don't talk about C, I wrote a pseudo-code. And I don't understand why vote down with a correct algorithm... For Java there is Long.MIN_VALUE, for C I don't know

Comment: @Daniele The question is tagged as `c`.